# Adding imaginary number "i" raised to high exponents

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm answering an MCQ regarding the topic. Some of my answers to the questions doesn't match the answer key. (It has no solution only the final answer.) I just want to know whether I'm right or wrong or maybe the key to corrections is erroneous. Just a yes or no is suffice or a tip if its wrong.

1.) Simplify the expression $i^{1999} + i^{1999}$ where I is an imaginary number.

- $i^{1996} \cdot i^3 + i^{1996} \cdot i^3$
- $i^{1996}$ cancels out as it is equal to 1, so: $i^3 + i^{3} =$ **-2i**

However, the answer key states that the correct answer is 0.

2.) Evaluate $4i^{410} - i^{864} + i^{601} + i^{1203}$

- $4(i^{408} \cdot i^{2}) - i^{864} + i^{600} \cdot i^1 + i^{1200} \cdot i^3$
- Those with exponents divisible by 4 will be equal to 1, so : $4i^2 - 1 + i + i^3 = $ **-5**

But the answer key states that the correct answer should be 3.

3.) If $i^2 = -1$, then $i^7 - i^6 + i^5 = $ ?

- $i^4 \cdot i^3 - i^4 \cdot i^2 + i^4 \cdot i^1$
- $i^4$ is equal to 1 so: $i^3 - i^2 + i = $ **1**

But the answer key states that it should be **-i**

So, is there something wrong on how I answer this kind of questions? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: The first one can't be $0$, since it's just a single non-zero number (whatever $i^{1999}$ turns out to be, it's not $0$) added to itself.

Comment: Your answers are fine. In general I am suspicious of the "answers at the back of the book" and treat them with a grain of salt. They are usually produced as an afterthought, and are unlikely to be rigorously checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get

$i^{1999}=-i$, so $i^{1999}+i^{1999}=-2i$.

$4i^{410} - i^{864} + i^{601} + i^{1203}
=-4-1+i-i=-5$.

$i^7-i^6+i^5=-i+1+i=1$.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I thought what I'm doing is wrong due to consecutive problems with wrong correct answer on the choices.

Comment: The first question is peculiar, adding a number to itself. Could there be a misprint there? @Jayce

Comment: It is from a mobile app. Looking again on the questions just now, there is one where the given problem is $i^{1997} + i^{1999}$ in which the answer is 0. So maybe that was a copy paste of the problem but made an error with the numbers on it. @Lord Shark the Unknown